# Google Tasks and Calendar: Use in a server application

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

Imagine I have some application, which reads and writes data to Google Tasks and Google Calendar.

It works in the background, i. e. checks the data in regular intervals and updates them (without interaction with the user).

That is, the user logs into my application once, enters some settings and from that point on, the application works completely transparent.

Is it possible to implement such an application so that the user is NOT required to enter his Google password?

TIA

Dmitri

Comment: AFAIK, 2-legged OAuth was made just for this. However, I don't know whether Google Tasks API supports 2-legged OAuth.

Comment: Ad Tasks API: The answer can be found here - http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-tasks-api%2FDKmKxYUFRPY%2Fdiscussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Apps for Domain, your application can interact with Calendar and Tasks API on the behalf of its user without asking for permissions using 2 legged OAuth and your OAuth Domain key.

You should take a look at Nicolas Garnier's article about [Using 2-legged OAuth with Google Tasks API for Google Apps domain administrators](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins.html).

Hope that helps.